# Iteratively naming Pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like this should be super easy to do, but I can't find a solution.

I have a data file with 400 columns, none of the columns are labeled. Each set of four columns is a different experiment with different numbers of rows.

What I would like to do is label the columns something like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3... etc.

All of the solutions I've seen seem to presuppose that you have prelabeled but poorly named labels and that you just want to rename them. There must be an iterative method for doing something like this.

Comment: Probably not the best way, but you could use `df.columns = [str(i + (j/10)) for i in range(1, 101) for j in range(1, 5)]`

Comment: I'm beginning to think it might* be easier to load the data set four columns at a time and label them as I go?? Maybe?

Comment: Similar to @Josmoor98 with format string `df.columns = [f'{i}.{j}' for i in range(1,101) for j in range(1,5)]`

Comment: How are you loading your data? If you’re reading from a csv, you can add the column names as a list

Comment: @Josmoor98, I hadn't thought of pre-labeling from a list like that, but it actually worked very well! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a DataFrame with a MultiIndex for the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(<your data here>, 
                    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(1, 101), range(1, 5)]))
```